# Laravel Inertia.js link with id

Tags: laravel-8, inertiajs

I want to pass an id from the `web.php` routes of my Laravel site and I receive error.

Here is my web.php:

```
Route::get('/member/{member}/show', [MemberController::class, 'show'])->name('member.show');
```

My route/href is setup like this:

```
<inertia-link class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" href="/member/{{ member.id }}/show">
```

Can anyone help me fix the `href="/member/{{ member.id }}/show"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use

```
<InertiaLink :href="route('member.show', { id: member.id })">
 show
</InertiaLink>
```

for more info [here](https://sebastiandedeyne.com/handling-routes-in-a-laravel-inertia-application/)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to link to a new `vue component`, send an `id` and show the `id` in the `url`, you can do this:

`Vue side`:

```
<template>
  <button @click="submit">Open page with id in url</button>
</template>


<script setup>
import {Inertia} from "@inertiajs/inertia";

const submit = () => {
    const id = 1
    Inertia.post('/yourUrl/' + id, {id: id}) //{id: id} key-value-pair of id
}
</script>
```

`Laravel side (web.php)`:

```
Route::post('/yourUrl/{id}', function (Request $request) {
    return inertia('yourVueComponent', ['id' => $request->id]);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment yet so I'll post this as an answer.

@mohamed-elshazly is nearly correct but got one minor detail wrong:

```
<InertiaLink :href="route('member.show', { member: member.id })">
 show
</InertiaLink>
```

It's like that, the parameter in the route is called {member} so you pass it an object with a member parameter: { member: yourVariableForMember }

Whatever the parameter in your route is called, you use that in place of member.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying below code its working fine

```
<Link
                href={route("member.subscription.form", { membershipId: id })}
            >
                <button
                    className="inline-flex w-full justify-center rounded-lg bg-theme-orange px-5 py-2.5 text-center text-sm font-medium text-white hover:bg-theme-orange focus:outline-none focus:ring-4 focus:ring-cyan-200 dark:focus:ring-cyan-900"
                    type="submit"
                >
                    <p>Choose plan</p>
                </button>
            </Link>
```